# Unit Test - New Operator - Redesign and Inject

Tags: unit-testing

The following class is very hard to unit test:

```
public class UserService
{
    public void Update(User user)
    {
        UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
        userDAO.update(user);
    }
}
```

In chapter 7.6.2 of the book Practical Unit Testing with JUnit and Mockito, Tomek Kaczanowsk suggest we should inject as following:

```
public class UserService
{
    private UserDAO _userDAO;

    public UserService(UserDAO userDao)
    {
        _userDAO = userDAO;
    }

    public void Update(User user)
    {
        _userDAO.update(user);
    }
}
```

However, how can we use UserService without creating UserDao?

```
public class UserController
{
    public UserController()
    {
        // How do we initialize UserService without understanding about UserDAO here
    }

    public ActionResult Update()
    {
        var user = new User();
        _userService.Update(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an interface from UserService and pass that into the constructor of your UserController

```
public class UserController
{    
    public UserController(IUserService service )
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public ActionResult Update()
    {
        var user = new User();
        _service.Update(user);
    }
}
```

`IUserService` service will be passed to `UserController` through Factory or Dependency Injection framework (e.g. *Ninject*/*SimpleInjector*)

Comment: So the UserController must create an instance of IUserDAO?

Comment: No the service, pass the nessesary parameter to the service to instantiate the userdao

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard to unit test, you simply mock the DAO:

```
@Test
public void updateUser(@Mocked UserDAO dao) {
   User user = new User();

   new UserService().update(user);

   new Verifications() {{ dao.update(user); }};
}
```

This using the JMockit mocking library.